# Error while running postgres on ubuntubase docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm practicing the examples provided in book Docker in Practice chapter 3.
Below is the Dockerfile mentioned to run docker with postgres.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update \
   && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  apt-get install -y \
   postgresql \
   && apt-get clean \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /opt
COPY db /opt/db
RUN service postgresql start && \
   cat db/schema.sql | psql && \
   service postgresql stop
```

But the copy in the step 4 gives me the below error.

```
 $ sudo docker build -t db .
 Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
 Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> c69811d4e993
 Step 2/4 : RUN apt-get update     && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  
 apt-get install -y     postgresql     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf 
 /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2ac4ff885d29
 Step 3/4 : COPY db /opt/db
 COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder554911929/db: no such file or directory
```

when I commented the `COPY` command, I'm getting different error.

```
 Step 4/4 : RUN service postgresql start &&     cat db/schema.sql | psql &&     service postgresql stop
 ---> Running in 79e47b45c41a
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
 ...done.
 cat: db/schema.sql: No such file or directory
 psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY db /opt/db` is supposed to copy `db` from your current context (the folder you are executing `docker build` from)

So make sure said current folder *does* actually include the `db` folder.